# How to authenticate with spark-submit cluster mode?

Tags: apache-spark

I'd like to remotely run spark-submit from a local machine to submit a job to spark cluster (cluster mode). What method do I use to authenticate myself to the cluster?

Answer (score -1):

You need to be on spark client machine to submit a job. Once you are in spark client and after you submit a job, you will be authenticated by user id by which you are submitting job. If your user id has permissions on cluster it will be taken care automatically. For kerberos enabled you need to generate keytab first for that session and user to authenticate with cluster.